# Capturing more then 5 mouse buttons - Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, button, mouse

I'm trying to get more then the usual 3 mouse buttons events via WM_RBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_MBUTTONDOWN. So I discovered the raw input method in the following tutorial using WM_INPUT and RAWINPUTDEVICE.

http://toymaker.info/Games/html/raw_input.html

But That one only gives me information about the first 5 buttons (including the 3 regular ones). Does anybody know how to get more? It would be nice if it was a windows api alone solution.

Comment: Buttons beyond the 8 standard buttons rely on custom implementations provided by the vendor's driver. The Raw Input API will give you access to the information provided by the driver, but it will not provide additional semantics for interpretation. Consult the device vendor for information. If - however - those additional buttons aren't actually mouse buttons, they likely generate keyboard input, and are reported as such.

Comment: Also, your final paragraph reads wrong. The `RAWMOUSE` structure supports 5 buttons **in addition to** the 3 regular buttons (left/middle/right). In other words: It will report information for 8 different mouse buttons, not just 5 (as I assume you implied).

Comment: @IInspectable: Based on [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645578.aspx) and looking in `winuser.h`, `RAWMOUSE` can report up to 5 buttons (left, middle right, x1, and x2) and the vert/horz wheels.  This is also consistent with the `WM_...BUTTONDOWN/UP` window messages, which only support up to 5 buttons (left, middle, right, x1 and x2). There are no defines/messages for more buttons than that. Do you have a mouse that reports events for more than 5 buttons?

Comment: @Remy: I overlooked that the first 3 `RI_MOUSE_BUTTON_<n>_...` constants alias left/middle/right button. Thanks for the correction. There are devices with more than 5 buttons (e.g. [Razer Naga Epic](http://www.razerzone.com/store/razer-naga-epic)). As far as I know, the additional buttons are reported as keyboard input, though.